# Использование тире для указания на автора/источник сообщения

Tags: пунктуация, тире, прямая-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, грамотно ли ставить тире, как это делают новостные каналы, для обозначения того, от кого поступила информация? Какое правило тут действует? Вот реальные (насколько помню) примеры.

*Режим ЧС введён в Курганской области — МЧС.*

*Процентная ставка будет повышена — Эльвира Набиуллина.*

*Качественные изменения рынка труда предполагают рост заработных плат — Путин.*

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (06.08.2023)**

"Грамота.ру" ответила так (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310755)):

> На возможность оформления прямой речи без кавычек в текстах СМИ указывает, в частности, Д. Э. Розенталь, см. «Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация», [параграф 47.4](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827535.html).

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях имя автора заключается в скобки. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=166#pp166

Comment: В параграфе 47.4 есть слова, вводящие слова автора. Но их нет в нашем примере.

Comment: Вам везёт, Грамота ру отвечает на все ваши вопросы.

Comment: Эх, если бы... Некоторые вопросы периодически задаю им месяцами.